# Plotting multilpe Columns on Seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I got this [DataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kBDyb.png)

And I want to use "Tiempo" as x-axis for the columns "Promedio","1","2","3",etc..
all in the same graph using seaborn or anything that can accomplish a scatterplot with many columns.

I can't figure it out yet , please help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the `tiempo` column as an index with `df.set_index("tiempo")` and if you use the internal function of the dataframe `df.plot` you will see the time in the `x` axis.